# How to avoid writing to DOM while scrolling?

Tags: javascript

I need to change container heading according to what child is scrolled into view at the moment. The container has fixed height and overflow:hidden

The HTML is something like this:

```
<h2 class="heading">Item 1</h2>
<div class="dealers-scrollable">
    <div class="dealer-group">
        <h3 class="group-head">Item 1</h3>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="dealer-group">
        <h3 class="group-head">Item 2</h3>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="dealer-group">
        <h3 class="group-head">Item 3</h3>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
$(".dealers-scrollable").mCustomScrollbar({
    callbacks: {
        whileScrolling: function(){
            changeHeading(this);
        }
    }
});

var changeHeading = (function () {

    return function(el) {
        var blockPosition,
            elementPosition,
            currentHeading;

        $(".dealer-group").each(function () {
            blockPosition = Math.abs(el.mcs.top);
            elementPosition = $(this).position().top;

            if (blockPosition > elementPosition) {
                currentHeading = $(this).find(".group-head").text();
                $(".heading").text(currentHeading);
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

This code does the job. But the problem is it writes into DOM on every scroll even if the current block is still in view. This is bad and I want to avoid it. I wrapped the function in closure and wanted to use a flag, but with no luck. 
Please advise what can be done to avoid constant wring to DOM on scroll?
https://jsfiddle.net/gwht91cj/

Comment: Please, create a JSfiddle

Comment: Mix it up with a little of [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SnJXQ/2/) When greater then 70% add new content?

Comment: @leo.fcx please check it.

Comment: I don't think you need the IIFE. Can't you put the current heading text in a variable before starting the each loop, and then in the loop only write to the DOM if the required heading text is different? (Also, within the each, when  you find the current element you can return false to stop the loop, rather than continuing to the end every time.)

Comment: @nnnnnn, I wrapped the function in IIFE because I was fiddling with a flag variable, but to no luck. I tried writing the heading into a variable, but that didn't help. Maybe you can come up with a solution? The problem is it overwrites the heading on every scroll.

Comment: Yes, so as I already said, use a variable to keep track of what the heading is, and only write to the DOM if the heading changes. Add another if inside your existing if to test that.

Comment: @nnnnnn I tried that first, but take this example. You have just scrolled to `Item 3`. In the `.each`, `Item 1` will detect the heading as different, and write, then `Item 2` will do the same, before finally `Item 3` does it. This will happen every time you scroll when multiple sections have been scrolled past. I used an array to store each element index that has been scrolled past, and text will only be written to DOM if the index of the element also matches the last piece of data in the array (the bottom-most element index). That way, the example above will not happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwht91cj/2/)

What I did was create a variable to store all the blocks currently in view (or scrolled past), and used a `.each()` to add each index to the array:

```
var elemIndexInView = []

// Add index of each element that has been scrolled past
$(".dealer-group").each(function(index) {
    blockPosition = Math.abs(el.mcs.top);
    elementPosition = $(this).position().top;
    if (blockPosition > elementPosition) {
        elemIndexInView.push(index)
    }
});
```

Then, inside your original `.each()` loop, I changed the `if` statement  to this:

```
if (blockPosition > elementPosition) {
    currentHeading = $(this).children(".group-head").text();
    if (
        $('.heading').text() != currentHeading &&
        index == elemIndexInView[elemIndexInView.length - 1]
    ) {
        $(".heading").text(currentHeading);
        // alert('Written to DOM')
        // alert(currentHeading)
       }
}
```

---

```js
$(".dealers-scrollable").mCustomScrollbar({
    callbacks: {
        whileScrolling: function() {
            changeHeading(this);
        }
    }
});

var changeHeading = (function() {

    return function(el) {
        var blockPosition,
            elementPosition,
            currentHeading;
        var elemIndexInView = []

        // Add index of each element that has been scrolled past
        $(".dealer-group").each(function(index) {
            blockPosition = Math.abs(el.mcs.top);
            elementPosition = $(this).position().top;
            if (blockPosition > elementPosition) {
                elemIndexInView.push(index)
            }
        });

        $(".dealer-group").each(function(index, element) {
            blockPosition = Math.abs(el.mcs.top);
            elementPosition = $(this).position().top;

            if (blockPosition > elementPosition) {
                currentHeading = $(this).children(".group-head").text();
                if (
                    $('.heading').text() != currentHeading &&
                    index == elemIndexInView[elemIndexInView.length - 1]
                ) {
                    $(".heading").text(currentHeading);
                    // alert('Written to DOM')
                    // alert(currentHeading)
                }
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

```css
.dealers-scrollable {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mcustomscrollbar/3.0.6/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mcustomscrollbar/3.0.6/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h2 class="heading">Item 1</h2>
<div class="dealers-scrollable">
    <div class="dealer-group">
        <h3 class="group-head">Item 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat consequuntur nemo accusamus expedita minima, tenetur, esse nisi vel voluptas totam reiciendis harum dolorum similique voluptatem commodi deserunt, earum veritatis animi.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat consequuntur nemo accusamus expedita minima, tenetur, esse nisi vel voluptas totam reiciendis harum dolorum similique voluptatem commodi deserunt, earum veritatis animi.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat consequuntur nemo accusamus expedita minima, tenetur, esse nisi vel voluptas totam reiciendis harum dolorum similique voluptatem commodi deserunt, earum veritatis animi.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat consequuntur nemo accusamus expedita minima, tenetur, esse nisi vel voluptas totam reiciendis harum dolorum similique voluptatem commodi deserunt, earum veritatis animi.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dealer-group">
        <h3 class="group-head">Item 2</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat consequuntur nemo accusamus expedita minima, tenetur, esse nisi vel voluptas totam reiciendis harum dolorum similique voluptatem commodi deserunt, earum veritatis animi.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat consequuntur nemo accusamus expedita minima, tenetur, esse nisi vel voluptas totam reiciendis harum dolorum similique voluptatem commodi deserunt, earum veritatis animi.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat consequuntur nemo accusamus expedita minima, tenetur, esse nisi vel voluptas totam reiciendis harum dolorum similique voluptatem commodi deserunt, earum veritatis animi.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat consequuntur nemo accusamus expedita minima, tenetur, esse nisi vel voluptas totam reiciendis harum dolorum similique voluptatem commodi deserunt, earum veritatis animi.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat consequuntur nemo accusamus expedita minima, tenetur, esse nisi vel voluptas totam reiciendis harum dolorum similique voluptatem commodi deserunt, earum veritatis animi.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat consequuntur nemo accusamus expedita minima, tenetur, esse nisi vel voluptas totam reiciendis harum dolorum similique voluptatem commodi deserunt, earum veritatis animi.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dealer-group">
        <h3 class="group-head">Item 3</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat consequuntur nemo accusamus expedita minima, tenetur, esse nisi vel voluptas totam reiciendis harum dolorum similique voluptatem commodi deserunt, earum veritatis animi.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat consequuntur nemo accusamus expedita minima, tenetur, esse nisi vel voluptas totam reiciendis harum dolorum similique voluptatem commodi deserunt, earum veritatis animi.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat consequuntur nemo accusamus expedita minima, tenetur, esse nisi vel voluptas totam reiciendis harum dolorum similique voluptatem commodi deserunt, earum veritatis animi.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat consequuntur nemo accusamus expedita minima, tenetur, esse nisi vel voluptas totam reiciendis harum dolorum similique voluptatem commodi deserunt, earum veritatis animi.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat consequuntur nemo accusamus expedita minima, tenetur, esse nisi vel voluptas totam reiciendis harum dolorum similique voluptatem commodi deserunt, earum veritatis animi.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah! Thanks, I got your logic. It works as expected.
The duplicated loop looks a little strange, but I think it's ok.

Comment: No problem! I also agree the duplicate loop looks a little strange. You could merge them into one, but you need to be able to see the next itme in the `.each()` loop. I think it is possible to do that, but it is much easier to just have 2 loops.